# Solutions for allowing users to submit large files (1 - 5 GB). Thoughts?

Tags: email, file-upload, ftp, uploading

My customer has a need to be able to receive large video files his site members(1 - 5 GB, maybe larger if possible).  Hopefully I can get some good ideas from the overflow community on this

My origonal thoughts are to some how set up a file send site where only members can log in and e-mail their video's in.  Would this be tough to create?  Perhaps there are already some services out there that would authenticate my user's and allow them to email large files(The cost maybe worth it).

Would some sort of FTP Solution also be an available option?  I would have to know which user is uploading files.  I've never done an FTP upload site before.

Any thought or helpful links would be great!  Thanks!

Comment: I think you can rule out email for sending files this large. In our experience (cloudmailin.com) most email servers will accept a max of around 25mb, gmail is about 34mb. We personally decided to say 50mb max as it was above everything we could find and it's the sending servers that will cause the bottleneck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One option would be to build some kind of client side uploader which would allow you to measure progress, resume uploads etc

Possible technologies could include Silverlight, Java Applet or Flash

See [silverlight example on codeplex](http://silverlightuploader.codeplex.com/)

Comment: That's interesting that the silverlight solution says you can upload "files of any size".  That would be pretty impressive. I think flash only guarantees 100MB.

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that our company has a filesend that anyone can use as long as they are e-mailing a company employee.  This should work for me otherwise I think I would try the Silverlight uploader though..  haven't had too much luck with the Flash uploaders(plus there's a flash session bug that you need a work around for.  Cheers's